# How to implement paging in Azure Iot device twin queries

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

The azure documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language says that “*Azure IoT SDKs support paging of large results*” but I could not find any sample or reference on how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's based on the REST API POST calls and headers such as *x-ms-max-item-count* and *X-Ms-Continuation* , see the following screen snippets:

[image: query-firstpage]

[image: query-nextpage]

[image: query-lastpage]

as you can see the above last picture doesn't return a continuation header, therefore this page is last one.

- in addition, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language for paging examples using service SDKs.

Comment: Thank you very much! I saw the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#nodejs-example but it requires using the same query object and does not work for disconnected state, like between web requests. I can persist X-Ms-Continuation token between requests and your answer works great! What do I have to do if I want to skip a page? For example, if I want the fourth page without retrieving the previous pages?

Comment: there is no documented built-in mechanism for skipping a page, you have to always get the next continuation token. But, you can try to modify a continuation token for skipping devices. Note, that the continuation token = base64encoded text for example skip=0&total=10&last=Device12, where skip is always 0, so try to change it. The mandatory parameters for continue token are skip and total. Example for skipping the first 10 devices: skip=10&total=0, so after base64encoding, the x-ms-continuation:c2tpcD0xMCZ0b3RhbD0w

Answer (score 3):

Using [Azure IoT device SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/tree/master/device)

```
var Registry = require('azure-iothub').Registry;
var connectionString = '{iothub connection string}';
var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var pageSize = 10;
var query = registry.createQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", pageSize);
```

To get the first page:

```
query.next(function (err, devices, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to query devices: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        var continuationToken = response.headers["x-ms-continuation"]; // Example: "c2tpcD0wJnRvdGFsPTEwJmxhc3Q9ZGV2aWNlMTA="
        var pageToken = new Buffer(continuationToken, 'base64').toString('ascii'); // Example: "skip=0&total=10&last=device10"
        //Optionally, you may persist the token and use it for the next pages
    }
});
```

To get the next page,

```
query.next(continuationToken , function (err, devices, response) {…} //previous token
```

To get the fourth page

```
var pageNumber = 3; // zero based
var pageToken = "skip=" + pageNumber * pageSize + "&total=" + pageSize; // "skip=30&total=10"
var continuationToken = new Buffer(pageToken).toString('base64'); //"c2tpcD0zMCZ0b3RhbD0xMA=="
query.next(continuationToken, function (err, devices, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to query devices: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        //…
    }
});
```

Using [Azure IoT service SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/service)

Install Microsoft.Azure.Devices nuget package

```
    string connectionString = "{iot hub connection string}";
    int pageSize = 10;
    var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", pageSize);

    Console.WriteLine("First page");
    var firstPage = query.GetNextAsTwinAsync();
    var response = (QueryResponse<Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.Twin>)firstPage.Result;
    var continuationToken1 = response.ContinuationToken;
    response.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.DeviceId));

    Console.WriteLine("Next page");
    var nextPage = query.GetNextAsTwinAsync(new QueryOptions() { ContinuationToken = continuationToken1 });
    nextPage.Result.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.DeviceId));

    Console.WriteLine("Fourth page");
    var pageNumber = 3; // zero based
    var pageToken = "skip=" + pageNumber * pageSize + "&total=" + pageSize; // "skip=30&total=10"
    var continuationToken3 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pageToken)); //"c2tpcD0zMCZ0b3RhbD0xMA=="
    var fourthPage = query.GetNextAsTwinAsync(new QueryOptions() { ContinuationToken = continuationToken3 });
    fourthPage.Result.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(d.DeviceId));
```

Note: I don't know why but I got "missing API 2!" error when I use .NET Core.